# how to return the class function in python?

Tags: python

I called the other function from the first function.
when I return the first function, I am getting python None on the screen.

```
class test():

    def test1(self, userinput):

        return self.test2(userinput)

    def test2(self, urls):

        string = "this is " + urls
        self.test3(string)

    def test3(self, sentence):
        return sentence


if __name__ == "__main__":

    objectt = test()
    seek = "concept of my functions"
    print(objectt.test1(seek))
```

Comment: The test2 function doesn't return anything, so it returns None by default

Comment: Please learn about [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Attempting to explain the code to a "rubber duck" (or roommate, friend or other suitable substitute) often helps.

Answer (score 2):

In `test2`, you call `test3`.

`test3` returns `'this is concept of my function'` to test2. Then, test2 returns nothing to `test1` - so, as all functions that don't return anything specific, it returns `None`, which in turn is returned by `test1`.

You have to return the output of `test3` at the end `test2`: class test():

```
class test:
    def test1(self, userinput):

        return self.test2(userinput)

    def test2(self, urls):

        string = "this is " + urls
        return self.test3(string)

    def test3(self, sentence):
        return sentence


objectt = test()
seek = "concept of my functions"
print(objectt.test1(seek))

# this is concept of my functions
```